# SQL Query: Remove duplicates in column that is not primary key

Tags: sql

I have a table with multiple columns, namely, Title, Url, Description and an integer Id which serves as the primary key.

In the tables, there are multiple entries with the same title but different url, description and of course different Ids.

What would be the SQL query to obtain the rows that have unique Titles. With rows with the same title, it doesnt matter which row is return.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are *not* the same thing.  Which DBMS are you really using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.Title, t1.Url, t1.Description, t1.id
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(id) AS min_id
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY title
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.min_id
```

This will pick the record having the minimum `id` for each distinct value of `Title`.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: @PranavMalhotra Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Yeap will do, thanks for the help! (: